# Apache2 merge multiple Set-Cookie headers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, http-headers

We have a server running varnish. In order that it works correctly with Magento it analyses whether a Set-Cookie: EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE=1 header is passed through.

Only problem is that we have several headers (3 or 4) that start with "Set-Cookie:". Varnish has a limitation that it can only analyze the first "Set-Cookie" header.

Therefore I would like to ask how I could merge these multiple set cookie headers? I have been looking around on this for the last 4 days without any luck =(

Maybe using mod_header of apaches but I'm not really sure what the correct approach would be?

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**PS:** Running Debian and Apache 2.2.9

EDIT: Here are example headers containing the multiple set-cookie lines:

```
root@magento-development:/# curl -I http://XXXXXXXXX
[1] 5332
root@magento-development:/# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 14:49:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13
Set-Cookie: store=scfr; expires=Fri, 09-Nov-2012 14:49:56 GMT; path=/; domain=XXXXXXXXX; httponly
Set-Cookie: frontend=9ac04aa3912eb78eb79f98dd531f7ba6; expires=Thu, 10 Nov 2011 15:49:57 GMT; path=/; domain=XXXXXXXXX; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 16:49:57 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE=1; expires=Thu, 10-Nov-2011 15:49:57 GMT; path=/; domain=XXXXXXXXX; httponly
X-Cache-Debug: 1
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: modified apache config to match post requirements

First, merging cookie headers is a bad idea. See [what Apache folks have to say about it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/known_client_problems.html#cookie-merge) .

Second, multiple set-cookie headers are supported by protocol specification. If varnish can't handle multiple set-cookie headers that should be considered a bug and reported.

Third, can't you make the dont-cache-this varnish rule dependent on another custom header? like X-Magento-NoCache that you can setup from app or from apache ?  must it be a cookie?
e.g.

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store
rewriterule .* - [E=MAGENTO_DONT_CACHE:1]

header add X-Magento-NoCache 1 env=MAGENTO_DONT_CACHE
```

Comment: Ok merging cookies might be a bad idea indeed. Secondly: Ticket has been created: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/1058 . Third: It's an encrypted commercial module that handles the application site, since it's encrypted that's a dead end too.

Comment: modified my post, added rewrites to conditionally set an env variable if a ___store is found in query string. then set the custom header only if env var was set. you may want to put that inside a <location /magento> tho so you won't accidentally match other apps using ___store in qs. or just add one more rewritecond to make sure you match magento urls with ___store in qs

Comment: it doesn't matter for you if it's encrypted; you do the setups in apache and varnish

Comment: Didn't have enough time left at work, will try it on monday and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone might come up with a better answer, but you might find find this provides hope for the future or a good last resort if you're willing to build a new version yourself:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/866